# Confusion with word gastgebend

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was recently reading a document and I found the word `gastgebend` for me the meaning is not very clear, that is why i have 2 questions.

1. Is it referring to the person being the host or the guest?
2. what it a specific word to refer to the guest person?

Thank you very much in advance, i appreacite every comment or input

Comment: Can you please give us the complete sentence in which "gastgebend" occurs?

Comment: "gastgebend" is an unwieldy and uncommon adjective. I suspect you're reading a text where someone tried to translate a construction involving e.g. a "host/hosting country" too literally.

Comment: @KilianFoth Or perhaps something in gendering-context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The noun [*Gastgeber*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gastgeber) refers to the *host*. It is derived from the old phrase *Gast geben*, which means something like *to offer night shelter*. The adjective *gastgebend* is the participle from this verb and, therefore, refers to the person who is the host.

The noun *Gast* refers to the *guest*. An adjective that refers to the person who is the guest is *gastierend*. It is the participle from the verb *gastieren*, which means something like *to guest* or *to make a guest appearance*. Notice that the verb is also common today for artists who perform on a stage. So, sentences like *Der berühmte Schauspieler gastierte an der Volksbühne* does not mean that the actor spent the night there as a guest.

Mnemonic:

- Die *gastgebende* Person nennt man den *Gastgeber*.
- Die *gastierende* Person nennt man den *Gast*.

Comment: "An adjective that refers to the person who is the guest is *gastierend*." Do you have an example where the adjective or verb is used to refer to a guest (and not an actor or singer making a guest appearance)? Is this common usage (as is suggested by the phrasing that the meaning *make a guest appearance* is ***also** common*)?

Comment: It seems to me that "gastieren" is not used for a person visiting other persons (in the context of a private invitation).  A well-known artist, an orchestra and a football team can "gastieren" somewhere else (in the context of an official event).

Comment: @PaulFrost yeah, in that situation you would say "ich besuche dich" rather than "ich gastiere bei dir" (except if you mean it as a joke). "Gastieren" is more for situations where you would use the expression "guest star" in English.

Comment: @rob74 Another variant is "ich bin bei ... zu Gast".

Comment: And beware of simple rules in German - gastieren can also be used the other way around:
`Willst nicht Salz und Schmalz verlieren, 
Mußt, gemäß den Urgeschichten,
Wenn die Leute willst **gastieren**,
Dich nach Schnauz' und Schnabel richten.`
(_J.W.v.Goethe, Fuchs und Kranich_)